# Display data in antd table based on selected item from select option

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need to display data on the antd table based on the selected item from select option.The data that are to be displayed are stored in different variables. For example, if school is selected from select option then the datasource is available in schoolData and similarly for other option.
Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Framework from "../framework/Framework";
import { Dropdown, Button, Table, message, Select } from "antd";
import { DeleteOutlined, DownOutlined, EditOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { Content } from "antd/lib/layout/layout";
import AddNewButton from "../addNewButton/AddNewButton";
import "./attributes.css";
import DataSource from "./Datasource";
import IconDescription from "../icondescription/IconDescription";
import Modal from "antd/lib/modal/Modal";
import { Option } from "antd/lib/mentions";



const Attributes = () => {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

    const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false)

    // const [layer, setLayer] = useState()

    const columns = [
        {
            title: "S.N",
            dataIndex: "key",
        },
        {
            title: "Name",
            dataIndex: "name",
            key: "name",
            // render: (text) => <a>{text}</a>,
        },
        {
            title: "Address",
            dataIndex: "address",
            key: "address",
        },
        {
            title: "Contact No.",
            dataIndex: "contactno",
            key: "contactno",
        },
        {
            title: "Operation",
            dataIndex: "operation",
            key: "operation",
            render: () => {
                return (
                    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                        <IconDescription icon={<EditOutlined />} label="Edit" />

                        <IconDescription icon={<DeleteOutlined />} label="Delete" />
                    </div>
                );
            },
        },
    ];

    const addAttribute = () => {
        setIsModalVisible(true)
    }

    const modalHandleOk = () => {
        setIsModalVisible(false);
    };

    const modalHandleCancel = () => {
        setIsModalVisible(false);
    };

    const selectLayer = (e) => {
        console.log("select layer", e)
    }

    return (
        <Framework>
            <Content className="attributes">
                <div className="select-addNewBtn-container">

                    <Select defaultValue="school" style={{ width: 120 }} onChange={selectLayer}>
                        <Option value="school">School</Option>
                        <Option value="hospital">Hospital</Option>
                        <Option value="policeStation">Police Station</Option>
                    </Select>

                    <AddNewButton name={"Add New Attribute"} addNewBtn={addAttribute} />

                    <Modal title={"Add New Attribute"} visible={isModalVisible} centered onCancel={modalHandleCancel} onOk={modalHandleOk}>

                    </Modal>
                </div>

                <Table
                    dataSource={DataSource}
                    columns={columns}
                    className="data-table"
                    pagination={{
                        size: "small",
                        pageSize: 6,
                        hideOnSinglePage: true,
                        showSizeChanger: false,
                    }}
                />
            </Content>
        </Framework>
    );
};

export default Attributes;
```

How do i achieve the desired functionality? Do let me know. Quite a beginner at such things.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Datasource is just a simple array of data objects, and presumably you have another file eg: 'SchoolData' that you need to switch between when the select option is chosen.

What I'd do to keep it simple is create a react state variable to wrap your data and just set it at will in the `onChange` of your select.

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-x2iol4?file=src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you, that really helped. I was wondering if i were to provide different data for different layers, how can i display them since there might be any number of layers that can be added.

Comment: what do you mean by 'different layers'? do you have unique data for each corresponding select option? are the headers and shape of data the same or different?